# print binary data with php

Tags: php, http, get, binary

I want to echo binary data to be parsed by my http client. I'm working with HTTP GET and i have tried this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['mac'])) {
  if (isset($_GET['f'])) {
    switch ($_GET['f']){
  case 'get_maclist':
      $binarydata = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x00,0x10, 0x2C, 0x1B, 0x16, 0x4C, 0xDF, 0xCB, 0x00,     0x01);

  $header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.bin;";
  header($header);
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  echo $binarydata;
```

url i call:http://MyIP/test.php?mac=ABC&f=get_maclist

but what i receive in the file is different when looking at the binary file with a hex editor. How do I get this done correctly?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work well. Executing `od -x test.bin` shows `0000000 0000 2c10 161b df4c 00cb 0001`. How different from what you expect?

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was at a different spot in my code, simply because I forgot a break; in a switch() and it would load different data into the binary file than expected ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was at a different spot in my code, simply because I forgot a break; in a switch() and it would load different data into the binary file than expected ...